# mysql optimization

Tags: mysql, database, search, optimization

I am building a site with lots and lots of filters. Every time you click/narrow down your search, all counters get recalculated for all filters. I've realized that I have created somewhat of a problem here because on every click, I am recounting all filters by doing about ~50 count queries. This will create quite a significant database load when there are many users using the site at once..

The filter counters look like this in case you want more context: http://screencast.com/t/3bxrWTAtm

What is the best way to optimize these counts? I could use memcache but that would have to be cached for about 15-30 mins max as new listings could show up.

Here is an example of one of the COUNT queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS numOfRows FROM (SELECT `id`, `theLatitude`, `theLongitude`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(45.5086699) ) * cos( radians( theLatitude ) ) * cos( radians( theLongitude ) - radians(-73.5539925) ) + sin( radians(45.5086699) ) * sin( radians( theLatitude ) ) ) ) AS distance  FROM `housing` WHERE  (`elevator` = '1') AND ( `property-type` = 'loft' )  HAVING distance < 75) AS `newid`
```

Housing table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `housing` (
`id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
`user` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
`formatted_address` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
`theLatitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
`theLongitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
`property-type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`square-feet` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`bathrooms` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bedrooms` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`price` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`priceUSD` int(10) NOT NULL,
`currency` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`period` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`lease-terms` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`available-from` date NOT NULL,
`contactName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`contactPhone1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`contactPhone2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`cats` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`small-dogs` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`small-pets` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`big-dogs` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`alarm-system` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`air-conditioning` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`balcony` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`carpet-floors` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dishwasher` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`electricity` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fireplace` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`furniture` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heating` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`high-ceilings` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`hot-water` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`natural-gas` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`spa-hot-tub` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`refrigerator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stove` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`storage-space` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`walk-in-closets` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`washer-dryer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`doorman` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`elevator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`health-facilities` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`inside-parking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`laundry-facilities` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`outside-parking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`pool-sauna` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wheelchair-access` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`authnumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`validated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

There are 50+ fields that a user can filter by.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `indexes` do you have on your `housing` table?

Comment: I just started optimizing but I intend to put indexes on id, date, user, email, theLatitude and theLongitude. I'm not sure adding indexes to all the other fields would help.. although I am ok with indexing everything is that helps, even if it takes more space or slows down inserts/updates (those don't happen that often).

Comment: if anybody is looking for a pretty good slideshare about mysql EXPLAIN -> http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Explain` as suggested in hellohellosharp's answer.
2. Try to add `index` to attributes in your table.
3. Use Mysql cache.
4. Use memcached. Strongly suggest!

Comment: thanks everyone, ill award this answer as it is short. anybody reading, please read other answers for detailed explanation on explain/index/memcache

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar for a website in the past with categories and products. My approach was to first write one application call for each grouping of filters. In other words, one call to get your list of Features as an example.

Next you *absolutely* want to cache that call in your application/web code. You can cache function calls from your application or the service that powers your application. For example, if you had a function, "getListingFeatures()", you would cache that function in Memcached for 2 minutes. When it expires, it will of course go to the database and load it into cache again.

You can definitely set the expiration time to something low.

Also consider making your expiration times fairly random to avoid "Thundering Herds" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem).

I'd strongly encourage you to keep with it and use Memcached.

Comment: That was my initial thinking but I've got a latitude and longitude in my search which will strongly narrow down the search to a specific location so I don't think the users' coming in will match any existing query unless I cut down the lat/lng to maybe 2 digits after the decimal and even then it would be still quite narrow... I'm wondering if I could maybe query the db without lon/lng and then narrow it further without the db but then i'd get too many results back :) still kind of confusing.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  The use cases will be too varied for you to cache calls.  You would end up with 1,000 items in cache for 1,000 users.  Then the focus shifts to optimizing the database queries, putting in spinners for the UI so users know something is happening and maybe re-thinking having counts at all.  =)

Comment: yea but I really do want to have them and I know it is possible. An example would be http://www.vacationhomerentals.com/vacation-rentals/San-Francisco-Bay-Area-California.htm . They have searches with lat/lon although its per location so maybe theirs is slightly less narrowed down. I guess I'll a/b test various approaches and see how it works out. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `Explain` on your queries and see how many rows your mysql is having to examine. Try to get a sense of what's going on behind the scenes.

Second, if at all possible, use `Join` instead of nested queries. This is a lot lighter on mysql.

Third, experiment with different indexes on your filter columns.

EDIT: Bill Karwin taught me the 1,2,3 rule for indexes. That is, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `SELECT`. The columns in your WHERE statement are generally the most important to add indexes too.

Now, with a query that uses intense calculations like that, I can't say what indexes will work best for you which is why you should do some experimenting.

[Watch this slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) to learn the basics of indexes. All credit goes to Bill Karwin.

Comment: I am using ADODB which shows all queries that are taking too slow. It also catches errors and so on.
Everything right now is in one table, might be worth re-working that structure if it helps optimize.. but I am not sure how to re-organize it so I'll put that on hold for now :) unless someone can give me some specific guidance having the full table structure now